# how can i get some image link from google app engine?

Tags: image, google-app-engine

i'm soooo newbie for Google app engine.

i just want to put some testimage.jpg file to my GAE server and want to get some image link

like "http://team-abc.appspot.com/testimage.jpg"

i tried to put my images in folder, and by dev_appserver.py myapp, upload these images with

app.yaml(

- url: /images/(.*)

  static_files: static/images/\1

  upload: static/images/(.*)

)

but doens't work. :(

help me.

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

if your image is in the folderstructure static/images/testimage.jpg and you define the url for this static image to be

```
-url: /images/(.*)
```

then you should be able to get this image at the url

```
http://team-abc.appspot.com/images/testimage.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are newbie may be you can try this app engine boilerplate where one of its features is get image's links.

Good luck